# Android magic is reality! Can't understand

Tags: android, bundle

In class of system android sdk Bandle.class happened magic. I can't explain why compiler execute two returns! See on attached video. Anybody can explain what is trouble ?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ObOZ60OEse4&feature=youtu.be
Second case: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WB4k48MCST0&feature=youtu.be

Comment: anyone can explain me ? Or just minus post!

Comment: This is a very low quality question. You don't even explain what's the point of your question, instead you just included the video and expect people tell you what's happening. You should at least try yourself understanding what's happening, why, and then post it (and at the end you can also include the video, but with a worthy question).

Comment: I try understand many days. But my thinks about this are equals null! Don't understand how it's can happen. And I decided post this video and wait for are developers with experience explain me, what it is ?

Comment: Then probably Carl's answer will help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler isn't executing two returns. The code in the video is:

```
try {
  return (String) o;
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
  typeWarning(key, o, "String", e);
  return null;
}
```

The code is trying to cast the Object `o` to a String, but the cast fails and throws a `ClassCastException`, which is caught by the next line. Inside that catch block, it then returns `null` because it can't do the original String conversion.

Comment: Thank you so much! Okey! What happened in this case ?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WB4k48MCST0&feature=youtu.be

Comment: That one is much more unusual. You are just using the Step command, correct?

Comment: I've seen this sometimes when the underlying code is optimized - the debugger can show that it's stepping to the first `return` line because the compiler might have loaded up that line into memory (assuming the evaluation is true), but then catches that the evaluation is false and instead drops down to the correct `return` line. Obviously this isn't very clear from the development tool itself.

Comment: yeah! In android studio F8 hot key by default!

Comment: Result of return method is block "else".

Comment: Yes, as I said, although 'if' return is highlighted as you step through, it is not actually returning that value.